# MacBook Pro: USB 2.0 flash drives not working while USB 3.0 drives work fine

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, usb

I have a Late 2013 15 MacBook Pro. After updating it to macOS High Sierra 10.13.4, USB 2.0 flash drives has stopped working. They are simply not recognized by the operating system. However, USB 3.0 drives continue to work.

What is causing this? How do I resolve it?

Comment: any reason you aren't updating to 10.14.4?

Comment: Are you sure that the 2.0 flash drives are functional in other machines?

Comment: Some of the tips in this thread might help - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8404239.